# Bootstrap 3 Sidebar-nav Scroll Spy not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have my Sidebar-nav

```
 <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav">
        <li class="sidebar-brand"><a href="#">My Site</a></li>
        <li><a href="#start">Start</a></li>
        <li><a href="#feedback">Feedback</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section3">Sec3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section4">Sec4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

If i add `data-spy="scroll" data-target="sidebar-wrapper"` to `<body>` the ScrollSpy is not working. I was searching here at StackOverflow but all others had another Navbar with `<nav>` or `<span>`

Just to be sure:
I added 
`<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>` to my `<head>` so ScrollSpay should be loaded

Comment: This should work with `#sidebar-wrapper` as the data-target: http://bootply.com/111915

Answer (score 0):

There are two potential problems...

`data-target="sidebar-wrapper"` on `<body>` should be `data-target="#sidebar-wrapper"`.

`<ul class="sidebar-nav">` needs a nav class, for example: `<ul class="sidebar-nav nav nav-stacked">`

Need to ensure the links are resolvable as well. Review full docs...
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy

Comment: Thanks but it's still not working. Maybe because i'm using a different structure and classes. My Project is built on this template here: [link](http://startbootstrap.com/templates/simple-sidebar.html)